# AMD ROCm Issues (HSA_STATUS_ERROR_OUT_OF_RESOURCES and more)

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, gpu, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I was just trying to install AMD ROCm so that I could use PyTorch(GPU) for my PC. I was experiencing issues after I had installed it. I was watching this tutorial to install AMD ROCm on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efKjfBkjPlM and I was using this documentation page from AMD: https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html#ubuntu.

My Computer Specs:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic
Shell: bash 5.0.16
CPU: AMD A10-9700 @ 3.5GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R5 M230/ R7 M260DX / Radeon 520 Mobile  RAM: 8GB DDR4

Errors I was facing:

Whenever I typed into the terminal 'rocminfo' I faced this error:

```
Unable to open /dev/kfd read-write: Bad address
someone is member of someone group
hsa api call failure at: /src/rocminfo/rocminfo.cc:1142 Call returned HSA_STATUS_ERROR_OUT_OF_RESOURCES: The runtime failed to allocate the necessary resources. This error may also occur when the core runtime library needs to spawn threads or create internal OS-specific events.
```

I don't know whether this was an error but just for reference when I typed 'clinfo' I got:

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (3137.0)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 0
NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone could help even if its something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there are two things that need to occur for you to get rocm working.

First, your CPU/Motherboard must support PCIE Atomics. Its unclear whether Bristol Ridge Supports it, but also the PCIE lane needs to be direct (not translated).

Best guess, most likely you won't be able to get this working with your hardware.

There are also quite a number of manufacturers that don't properly implement the BIOS tables. ASUS is one of those manufacturers but there are others. (i.e. tested with a Ryzen 5 Raven Ridge CPU + Prime B450-Plus mainboard gets the exact same error and prior to the latest firmware update its accessible, i.e. if you don't update AGESA).

You can find more information posted here. Specifically, the part about Bristol Ridge support, and OEM/ODM choices.
https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm#supported-cpus